# Flame - onComplete and reset() removed from SpriteAnimation

Tags: flutter, flame

I used to be able to call

```
spriteAnimation.reset()
```

or

```
spriteAnimation.onComplete = (){}
```

But once I upgrade to flame 1.8.0, they got removed.

What are the new solutions for the above behaviors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have been moved to the `SpriteAnimationTicker` so that an animation class can be used by multiple components at the same time.

So if you have a a `SpriteAnimationComponent` for example, then you have the `reset` method and the `onComplete` callback on the ticker and they are used like this:

```dart
spriteComponent.animationTicker.reset();
spriteComponent.animationTicker.onComplete = (){};
```